# How to keep states in components while navigating with hash router inside a single page application

Tags: reactjs, react-router, single-page-application

I am building a single page application with React. The app makes a one time request to an API to retrieve a JSON list. The list is displayed in a grid with some informations. The "home" component has a search bar to filter the list. When the user clicks on an element the detail component is presented on full screen. If the user clicks on the back button from the browser, the text from the search bar (home component) is reset. How can I preserve the state in the home component?

This is the App component

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Route, HashRouter} from 'react-router-dom';
import './App.css';
import Home from './components/home/Home';
import Detail from './components/detail/Detail';

class App extends Component {

// Route
render() {
    return (
        <HashRouter>
            <div>
                <div className="content">
                    <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
                    <Route path="/detail" component={Detail}/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </HashRouter>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

This is one of the navigation link from Home component (it is an array of NavLink).

```
<NavLink className="Member-item" to="/detail"> Detail</NavLink>
```

This is when I query

[image]

This is after I come back from detail component to home component

[image]

Any help is really appreciated!

Comment: You need context , useReducer , callback

Comment: you need some global state management, either redux or contextAPI or something similar (there are a few options).... another way to do it is to use localStorage or cookies...however that will not be very scalable as your app may grow...